# Importing and evaluating text file

Tags: import

I appologise in advance if this was asked before, but I couldn't find the answer.

I have a huge amount of data collected in several lists that I need to analyse. I don't want to have all this data listed in my actual Mathematica file, because it would take an enormous amount of space in my notebook. Rather, I want to save it in an external .txt file and somehow import it. 
The .txt file is of a form:

```
a={1, 2, 3, 4};
b={5, 6, 7, 8};
c={9, 10, 11, 12};
```

and I am looking for a way to read it and evaluate it in the notebook without actually writing it down. I want to be able to then do operations on a, b, and c as if they were part of the notebook from the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried `Get["file.txt"]`?

Comment: I am an idiot. It worked, tnx.

Comment: This should be saved as a .wl file if it is a bunch of Wolfram Language code.